# Skip a line in junit test

Tags: junit

I am writing junit test case for a method. While doing so, there is an exception in a line which is calling another void method. Because of this, the next line is getting affected. I want to skip this line and continue execution. Anyone please suggest me the solution.

```
helperObject.methodCall(session);//Exception occurred inside this mthd
httpResponse = buildSuccessResponse(ccId);
```

So whatever exception occurred in first line, i want second line to be executed.(because of exception i dint get the code coverage).

Comment: Please provide the code in question.

Comment: Sorry. i cant post the cmplete code. i have given the sample line .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you don't understand the concept of unit tests: the idea is, that you execute a method completely. Meaning: you **never ever** want that your tests do call anything but the exact "production" code that you will later ship to your customers. There is no sense in testing test-specific code. You always test the code that will be running at the customer!

Thus: if you think that test case that needs to "exclude" certain parts of your "code under test"; then no: you don't do that.

Instead, you understand where that exception is coming from, and then you decide if that exception indicates a bug in your production code; or if that exception means that your unit test needs to do some more setup work.

Example:

```
class ProductionThingy {
    private DataBaseWhatever whatever;

    int foo() {
       whatever.doSomething();
       return computeSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
class ProductionThingyTest {

@Test
public void testFoo() {
  ProductionThingy underTest = new ...
  assertThat(underTest.foo(), is(some expected value))
```

So, if you now want to test this foo() method ... and the test fails because of a NullPointerException for example (because the field whatever is null) then the solution is **not** to magically exclude that call `whatever.doSomething()`.

What you would do instead is to ensure that your ProductionThingy *underTest* object does have a non-null value within "whatever"; for example using *dependency injection* in order to provide a *mocked* instance of DataBaseWhatever.

Comment: I liked the high-lighting "never-ever" :-)

Comment: Yeah, asterisk, an his brother asterisk-asterisk are my best friends around here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Jägermeister. now only i started writing junit. will check the code inside the methd call.

Comment: @programmer You are welcome. In any case; I would recommend you to learn "writing unit tests" from one (or more) of the many online tutorials out there. It is hard to get into unit testing ... by "just trying it"; and using isolated information, coming from google results on different search words ... Its easier to work through one "complete" tutorial, that walks you through the various aspects of unit testing in a consistent manner.